# DISTINCT (vs. Partition?)

Tags: sql, distinct, window-functions

I have a select statement that is pulling distinct, primarily want it distinct to be just on ContactId, but know it is impacting rest of data, and want to make sure additional records are not left out due to this.

I have seen aspects of using partition?  Not sure if that is the best way to declare distinct only on one column, especially with Joins and etc.

If there is a better way to apply distinct to just the initial column, very interested in better ways of doing this. Thanks!

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Optins_Nov2017.ContactId, Optins_Nov2017.Form, 
Optins_Nov2017.Contact_Name, Optins_Nov2017.Form_Id, LT_nov.Email, 
Optins_Nov2017.Form_Date, Optins_Nov2017.Lead_Source, LT_nov.ContactId, 
LT_nov.Total_Purchased, LT_nov.Date_Created, LT_nov.Num_Invoices, 
Subs_Nov.Start_Val

FROM Optins_Nov2017

JOIN LT_nov
ON Optins_Nov2017.ContactId = LT_nov.ContactId

LEFT JOIN Subs_Nov
ON Optins_Nov2017.ContactId = Subs_Nov.ContactId

WHERE Lead_Source = '$refpart'
AND Form_Date BETWEEN '$pdate' AND '$pdate2'
";
```

Comment: Since you're doing some processing in another language anyway, it is often easiest to _sort_ the data by the field which you'd make "distinct", and read groups of records with the same potentially repeating field (e.g. `ContactId`). When the value of `ContactId` changes, you're guaranteed to never see it again, so you can group duplicates and process them as you see fit in your language.

Comment: We don't know your data.  Only you know your data.  Just try without `DISTINCT`.  See if there are records that duplicate.  If there are, then `DISTINCT` will remove them.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: using PHP with MySQL